# Incompatible pointer type assigning

Tags: ios, nsdictionary

I have a static dictionary which has been initialised and data has been added into it in a different.m file, now in my view controller I need that static dictionary.
the dictionary actually contains carrier names as key and their respective number as values so what i want top do is check what carrier the phone belongs to and then get the corresponding number. 
The .m file where the static Dictionary has been formed is Config.m and it has a method that actually returns the static dictionary.

```
+ (NSDictionary*) getMccMncToCodeDictionary
{
    return mccMncLISDictionary;
}
```

what i did in my ViewController is:"Incompatible pointer type assigning to

```
Config* network_number = [[Config alloc] init];
network_number = [Config getMccMncToLISCodeDictionary];
NSLog(@"network number:::%@", network_number);
```

In my console it shows

```
network number:::(null)
```

The warning(yellow error) i get is "Incompatible pointer type assigning to 'Config*_strong' from NSDictionary*'" in the second line of the code in the ViewController

My initLISDictionary code:

```
- (void) initLISDictionary
{ 
NSString* MCC = @"520";
NSString* CAT3G = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@00",MCC];
NSString* AIS = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@01",MCC];
NSString* CAT_CDMA =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@02",MCC];
NSString* TOT3G = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@15",MCC];
NSString* DTAC = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@18",MCC];
NSString* AIS_GSM_1800 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@23",MCC];
NSString* TRUE_MOVE_H = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@88",MCC];
NSString* TRUE_MOVE = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@99",MCC];

mccMncLISCodeDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[mccMncLISCodeDictionary setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:2] forKey:CAT3G];
[mccMncLISCodeDictionary setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1] forKey:AIS];
[mccMncLISCodeDictionary setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:2] forKey:CAT_CDMA];
[mccMncLISCodeDictionary setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:4] forKey:TOT3G];
[mccMncLISCodeDictionary setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:3] forKey:DTAC];
[mccMncLISCodeDictionary setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1] forKey:AIS_GSM_1800];
[mccMncLISCodeDictionary setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:5] forKey:TRUE_MOVE];
[mccMncLISCodeDictionary setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:5] forKey:TRUE_MOVE_H];
}
```

Comment: This code doesn't even make sense.

Comment: show your full class codes

Comment: full class code as in the whole of config.m?

Comment: yes......whole from config.m

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course this will not work.

```
Config* network_number = [[Config alloc] init];
network_number = [Config getMccMncToLISCodeDictionary];
NSLog(@"network number:::%@", network_number);
```

This code initiates a new Config object, however when you call the network_number you are calling a CLASS method, so its worth nothing that you initiated it before. You need to make it an instance method (just change the + for the - and make sure its declared on the header) so that you can call:

```
Config* network_number = [[Config alloc] init];
network_number = [network_number getMccMncToLISCodeDictionary];
```

OR you would have to make your Class Method be totally self sufficient, but im sure its not what you want.

EDIT:

```
+ (NSDictionary*) getMccMncToCodeDictionary
{

NSString* MCC = @"520";
NSString* CAT3G = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@00",MCC];
NSString* AIS = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@01",MCC];
NSString* CAT_CDMA =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@02",MCC];
NSString* TOT3G = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@15",MCC];
NSString* DTAC = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@18",MCC];
NSString* AIS_GSM_1800 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@23",MCC];
NSString* TRUE_MOVE_H = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@88",MCC];
NSString* TRUE_MOVE = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@99",MCC];

mccMncLISCodeDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[mccMncLISCodeDictionary setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:2] forKey:CAT3G];
[mccMncLISCodeDictionary setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1] forKey:AIS];
[mccMncLISCodeDictionary setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:2] forKey:CAT_CDMA];
[mccMncLISCodeDictionary setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:4] forKey:TOT3G];
[mccMncLISCodeDictionary setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:3] forKey:DTAC];
[mccMncLISCodeDictionary setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1] forKey:AIS_GSM_1800];
[mccMncLISCodeDictionary setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:5] forKey:TRUE_MOVE];
[mccMncLISCodeDictionary setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:5] forKey:TRUE_MOVE_H];

return mccMncLISDictionary;
}
```

This is the closest it can be to what you seem to be trying to do.

Just use these 2 lines, ignore the init

```
NSMutableDictionary *network_number = [Config getMccMncToLISCodeDictionary];
NSLog(@"network number:::%@", network_number);
```

Comment: i actually changed it to `NSDictionary *network_number = [Config getMccMncToLISCodeDictionary];` based on the first answer although i still get a null, my new problem is I am supposed to initialise the mccMncLISCodeDictionary but that I am not able to do. what my new code is `[Config initLISDictionary];NSDictionary *network_number = [Config getMccMncToLISCodeDictionary];
NSLog(@"network number:::%@", network_number);`but My app stops running and throws an exception `uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[LISConfig initLISDictionary]: unrecognized selector sent `

Comment: You cannot initialize a class. Make an instance of this class and then initialize that instance, you can either do a init followed by a initLISDictionary or merge the init with the initLISDictionary. You get that exception because right now you only have an instance method, NOT a class method. But you cannot do that type of initialization in a class method. To make it super simple. Check my edit.

Answer (score 1):

Try making the `initLISDictionary` method a class method and then you can do the following:

```
+ (NSDictionary*) getMccMncToCodeDictionary
{
    if (mccMncLISDictionary == nil) {
        [Config initLISDictionary];
    }
    return mccMncLISDictionary;
}
```

However, you are also initializing `mccMncLISCodeDictionary` instead of `mccMncLISDictionary`, so you will need to straighten that out as well.

You should do:

```
NSDictionary *network_number = [Config getMccMncToLISCodeDictionary];
NSLog(@"network number:::%@", network_number);
```

since you are calling this method, whose return type is NSDictionary

```
+ (NSDictionary*) getMccMncToCodeDictionary
{
    return mccMncLISDictionary;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Those are all class methods which return static objects.

You probably want to do something like this:

```
NSDictionary *network_number = [Config getMccMncToLISCodeDictionary];
```

Comment: I need to initialise mccMncToLISCodeDictionary first right? how do i do that? I have to use the `initLisDictionary` method to do it but where and how do I do it, everything I try I get an exception and the app terminates